# how to handle devise's authenticate_user! with ajax call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a form with :remote => true which means it will be submitted through ajax.

In the controller, I have such code:

```
before_filter: authenticate_user!, :only => [:create]
```

For I only allow confirmed user to create resource.

However, when the authentication fails, devise will raise a

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized
```

and no unobtrusive javascript will be rendered.

But I hope things goes like this:

devise set some messages in flash, and render my .js.erb, then I show the flash to users.

How to achieve it?

Comment: I cannot believe... but I have got same problem currently with devise 2.0.0.rc ... I only add to your question that I really do not want change session controller create action... also overriding authenticate_user! seems to be ridiculous... navigational formats change in configuration (adding :js, :json) doesn't work for me

Answer (score 11):

It is quite funny but change in devise.rb http_authenticatable_on_xhr to false

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

did the trick for me... without overriding authenticate_user! method

> note: I also added :js to navigational formats

```
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :js]
```

Comment: it is logic in that... with flag set to true ajax request returns only headers for 401 - so for instance for json calls it is useful. When you want true body response you have to set this flag to false

Comment: Yes it works! But I still have a problem. When authentication fails, devise will render users/sign_in.js, how to change it? I mean I want to render my own js file and not necessarily in the public/users/ folder.

Comment: I am pretty sure users/sign_in.js.erb shouldn't be under public/users folder that you mentioned but inside app/views/users/sign_in.js.erb (or whatever you tell devise)

Back to your problem - I am afraid that give other view than callers' cannot be achieved without overriding authenticate_user!

Comment: It's not sign_in.js.erb...it is just sign_in.js, which can get from http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_up.js, so I put it under public/users and it does works. OK. I'm trying to find another way.

Comment: so I'm guessing we render the `sign_up` html partial in the `sign_up.js`?

Is there a way to just redirect it to the html view?

Comment: Works, but had to create sign_up.js file in /public/users folder. The JS itself is:
alert('You will be redirected to log in.');
window.location = '/users/sign_in';

Answer (score 2):

You need do your own authenticate_user! action and in this action you can have the behaviour your want.

```
def authenticate_user!
  unless current_user
    render 'my_js'
  end
end
```