# Devise authenticate_user! breaks when making remote: true requests to a non-devise controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, devise

I am having an issue with Devise' `before_action :authenticate_user!` filter on `remote: true` option.

I have a link tag which makes a normal PUT request to `messages#read` of my `MessagesController` below

`<%= link_to 'Mark Read/Unread', read_message_path(message), method: :put %>`

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :read
  before_action :set_message, only: :read
  ...
  #http PUT
  def read
    @message.toggle!(:read)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end 
  ...
end
```

If the user is not signed in, it redirects to the sign in page as the expected Devise behavior.

However when setting the **`remote: true`** option on the link e.g.

`<%= link_to 'Mark Read/Unread', read_message_path(message), method: :put, remote: true %>`

Devise breaks with error: `PUT http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.js 404 (Not Found)`

My logs output a `401 Unauthorized` followed by

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/users/sign_in.js")`

[image]

The problem is Rails tries to render `/users/sign_in.js` via PUT which does not exist and shouldn't. This is what trips me off and confuses me becasue I would exptect to be redirected to devise `/users/sign_in` html page and instead Rails tries to render a sign_in page with `.js` extension.

I tried setting `config/initializers/devise.rb` lines to

`config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false`

`config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :js]` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901781/how-to-handle-devises-authenticate-user-with-ajax-call).

I am using Devise with its default settings. No special routes nor controllers.

What am I missing here? am I misunderstading the way Devise is supposed to work?

Is there away to override `authenticate_user!` to redirect to devise' default sign_in html page on xhr requests?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while doing a jquery ajax call.
The strange thing is it was working with a button_to remote call.

My solution was to change the method to `POST` and expected response type to `script`:

```
  $.ajax({
          url: myurl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {myvar: myval},
          dataType: 'script',
```